# Using Filtering in AngularJS ngTable wih nested object property

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am stuck with `ng-table` filtering.

The sample in http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-nested-property says to use this syntax into markup, showing below. But it doesn't work when I try to make the filtering in my controller(code below).

Using the sample of the site when I get the filter object in controller, I get
`{tabela_tuss.descricao:"asda"}`. The correct will be: `{tabela_tuss:{descricao:"asda"}}`

I have:

//markup:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
 <tr ng-repeat="row in $data track by row._id">
 <td  data-title="'Descrição'" filter="{ 'tabela_tuss.descricao': 'text' }" >{{row.tabela_tuss.descricao}}</a></td>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In order to work, I need a filter as:

```
 filter="{ 'tabela_tuss:{'descricao': 'text' }}"
```

But, if I do that,  I get an error in angular  as:

```
angular.js:14328 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '}' is an unexpected 
token at column 37 of the expression [{ 'tabela_tuss:{descricao': 'text'} }] 
starting at [}].
```

I need that filter to use in my controller:
//controller

```
dataService.getProcedimentos().then(function (response){
        $scope.data=response.data;
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,
            sorting: {
              nome: 'asc'
            }
        }, 
        {        getData: function(params) {
                  var sdata = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) : $scope.data;
                  sdata = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(sdata, params.filter()) : sdata;
                  //sdata = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(sdata, {tabela_tuss:{descricao:'B'}}) : sdata;
                  console.log(params.filter());
                  params.total(sdata.length);
                  sdata = sdata.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                  return sdata;
                }
        }
        );
      });
```

My data sample is:

```
data:[
{_id: "5927043517e34011e48d8444", 
nome: "proced 1",
tabela_tuss:{id:1,descricao:'descr test'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting parse syntax error because there is a syntax error.
Change your filter from

```
       filter="{ 'tabela_tuss:{'descricao': 'text' }}"
```

to

```
       filter="{ 'tabela_tuss':{'descricao': 'text' }}"
```

Comment: I agree with you. I alread had tested it. But if I use it, I get an other error: "angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at t.getTemplateUrl (ngTableFilterConfig.ts:81)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15156), <anonymous>:4:306)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17806)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18080)
    at done (angular.js:12210)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12436)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12364)"